# Eonasdan DateTimePicker for bootstrap 3 not working

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, datepicker

I'm trying to use [this](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) datetimepicker for my Asp.Net MVC 5 project. The project uses default Bootstrap3 layout. The github project for this datetimepicker can be found [here](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker).

As mentioned is site I've incuded the the js and css file in my view.

for my datetimepicker i have copied the exact code from the site

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CreateAppointment_SetDate";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.min.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/moment.min.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/Bootstrap/transition.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/Bootstrap/collapse.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js")
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css"/>

}

    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class='well'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
            });
        </script>
    </div>
```

and this is what i see in view
[image]

The problem is when i click the calender icon, nothing happens. No datetimepicker, and the calendar icon is not clickable. In the console it says `Bootstrap requires jQuery` but there in network i can see jquery being loaded.

Can anyone suggest what the problem is?

**Edit1:**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CreateAppointment_SetDate";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.min.js")
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/moment.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
}



    @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.AppointmentId)
    <h3>When should appointment take place?</h3>
    <h4>Please select the date range for the appointment to take place between</h4>
    <h6>Please select a start date</h6>

    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class='well'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker2'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker();
            });
        </script>
    </div>
```

[image]
[image]

**Edit2**

the jquery.min.js is the file i got from the site, I looked the sites network copied the jquery.min.js file link and added to my project. When I comment  `@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.min.js")` line:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CreateAppointment_SetDate";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    @*@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.min.js")*@
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/moment.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
}



    @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.AppointmentId)
    <h3>When should appointment take place?</h3>
    <h4>Please select the date range for the appointment to take place between</h4>
    <h6>Please select a start date</h6>
    <div class ="container">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class='well'>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker2'>
                        <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function () {
                    $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker();
                });
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
```

In console:
[image]

Edit 2 with commenting `@*<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>*@` line
[image]

Comment: I can see you are using two different jQuery versions: choose one and retry again.

Comment: can you look into edit 1 may be

Comment: Don't load jQuery twice; what are the syntax errors? Do you have a live site or other scripts loaded?

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward can u look edit 2? And no i don't have live site

Comment: Have you edited any of jQuery/Moment/Datepicker js files? In case you did use original version otherwise try to use the unminimized version of datepicker and check if there's still the issue - maybe there's something wrong in the minimizing process.

Comment: i solved the problems, you can see the answer below

Comment: @Biplov13 did you get your problem resolved? Please let me know if I can be of any help

Answer (score 0):

You are using 2 jquery versions. I dont know which version jquery.min.js is ?

Try remove this line  `@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.min.js")`

Comment: I removed that, still doesn't work. I got the jquery.min.js from the same github project which the datetimepicker is. S

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how but the bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js had all the html codes from the css file. I then copied the js codes from the git project, now it seems to work fine.
On the other hand this is how it looks in example
[image]

and this is how it looks for me
[image]

Also, when I hover over dates i don't get hand icon, I get curson icon

Comment: it looks like the css isn't loaded. Do you still have an issue? You might also want to check out v4.